# How to check how many emails were sent between dates?

Tags: python

I want to count how many emails were sent between certain dates. The date header looks like this:

```
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 15:00:37 +0000
```

When counting other things, I code like this which adds one to the count:

```
if msg['From'] == 'example@example.com':
 count+=1
```

However it gets difficult when I have to count how many emails were sent between certain dates. Would it be something like:

date1= Tue, 18 Jan 2015 15:00:37
date2= Wed, 23 Jan 2015 15:00:37

```
if msg['Date'] < date2 and msg['Date'] > date1:
 count+=1
```

I Don't think python will recognize it being dates. Therefore the <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd> operators will not work?

Comment: check this out https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Are these dates stored as strings or datetime objects?

Comment: Strings. Thats why its not working :(

Comment: How can i make the msg['Date'] header into a datetime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dateutil or datetime to parse the strings as datetime objects and compare:

```
from dateutil import parser

date1= "Tue, 18 Jan 2015 15:00:37"
date2="Wed, 23 Jan 2015 15:00:37"
date1 = parser.parse(date1)
date2 = parser.parse(date2)
msg = {"Date": "Tue, 19 Jan 2015 15:00:37 +0000"}
if date2 >= parser.parse(msg['Date']).replace(tzinfo=None)  > date1:
     print msg['Date']
```

You will need to `pip install python-dateutil` as it is not in the standard lib.

Your Date string seems to include the timezone but date1 and 2 don't so you cannot compare offset-aware and offset-naive datetimes.